# как вывести текст страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, у меня есть шаблон страницы

```
<?php
    /*
        Template Name: Catalog Category
    */
?>
```

На этой странице я вывожу произвольные записи

```
<!-- Catalog Posts -->
                        <div class="catalog__posts">
                            <?php
                            $args = array(
                                'post_type' => 'post_type_1',
                                'publish' => true,
                                'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
                            );

                            query_posts($args);

                            if ( have_posts() ) :
                                ?>
                                <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                                <!-- Post -->
                                <div id="<?php the_ID() /* выводим ID поста */ ?>" class="catalog__post_card">
                                    <!-- Post Header -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col">
                                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                            <i class="status"
                                               data-status-true="Свободно"
                                               data-status-false="Занято"
                                               data-status-value="<?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_status', true)); ?>"
                                            ></i>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- / Post Header -->
                                    <!-- Post Body -->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <!-- List -->
                                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                                            <ul class="catalog__list_attr">
                                                <li>
                                                    <p>Грузоподъемность - кг. :         <span><?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_carrying_capacity', true)); ?></span></p>
                                                    <p>Вместимость ковша - м3 :         <span><?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_bucket_capacity', true)); ?></span></p>
                                                    <p>Эксплуатационная масса - кг. :   <span><?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_operating_weight', true)); ?></span></p>
                                                    <p>Глубина копания - м:             <span><?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_digging_depth', true)); ?></span></p>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- / List -->
                                        <!-- Price -->
                                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="flex_center">
                                                <div class="catalog__post_price" data-rate="<?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_rate', true)); ?>">
                                                    <?php echo (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'data_price', true)); ?>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- / Price -->
                                        <!-- Image -->
                                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">
                                            <div class="catalog__post_image">
                                                <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail( array(0,9999), array('class' => '') ); ?>
                                                <div class="flex_center">
                                                    <div class="catalog__post_buttons">
                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Подробнее</a>
                                                        <button>Заказать</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- / Image -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- / Post Body -->
                                </div>
                                <!-- / Post -->
                            <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                        <!-- / Catalog Posts -->
```

Как мне вывести текст который я добавляю в Админке Wordpress, не пост а именно текст страницы ?

Comment: Чем отличается в вашем понимании пост и текст страницы? Вообще, контент выводится с помощью `the_content()`

Comment: Пробовал писать  <?php the_content();?> Но он не выводит текст который я пишу в админке

Comment: `the_ID()` выводит, а `the_content()` не выводит? Чудеса...

Comment: Смотрите, у меня на этой странице уже выводятся записи и the_ID цепляется к записи, помимо записей мне еще нужно вывести текст, который редактируется в админке, просто текст самой страници.

Comment: Причем the_title у меня выводится а the_content действительно не выводится, действительно чудеса))

Comment: Попробовал просто снести все посты и поставить the_content выдает ошибку
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 310

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить данные текущей страницы через `global $post` или `get_post()`

```
global $post;
echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
```

Comment: Я сделал сейчас немного по другому
Перед выводом произвольных простов я сделал так
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

А на фронте уже поменял их местами